# XCode: Where is GCC installed?

Tags: macos, gcc

I've installed XCode v3.1.3 and am having difficulties using the rumored GCC that is installed along with it. -- I'm certainly able to use the XCode IDE to compile my programs but would like the flexibility of also using the command line...

Where's GCC?

Comment: I've got one in /usr/bin/gcc-4.2, but maybe I installed a separate gcc apart from Xcode -- can't remember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that when you installed the Developer tools you unchecked "UNIX Development Support", so the command line tools were never installed.  Delete your `/Developer/` directory and do a clean install of the tools; make sure to select "configure" during the installation process and ensure that the appropriate items are checked.

Answer (score 4):

Look in `/Developer/usr/bin`

Answer (score 1):

In `/usr/bin` you should find `gcc-4.0` and `gcc-4.2` and then there will be a symbolic link `gcc` which points to one of these (usually `gcc-4.2`).

As always, you can find out where any available command in your `PATH` is located using `which`, e.g.

```
$ which gcc
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion with "which gcc".  That was the first thing I tried (to no avail) as GCC is not in my "/usr/bin" .  Instead, it's in my "/Developer/usr/bin" that is not in my default PATH.

Comment: @Nate: sounds like you need to re-install Xcode - make sure that the Unix support option is checked.